# where does the energy for capillary action come from?

Tags: capillary-action

I think capillary action occurs because water molecules have a little magnetic field with poles so they can stack up on each other somewhat. When it happens though, where is the energy derived from to create this kinetic movement?

Comment: Related : [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3859/) and the links therein.