# How do some substances "get wet"?

Tags: condensed-matter

For example, paper's structural integrity decreases when it comes into contact with a liquid. What happens at the time of contact?

Answer (score 2):

There are a great many descriptions of wetting action; you can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetting).  If you are particularly interested in the wetting of paper, check out [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/when-water-climbs-up-a-piece-of-paper-where-is-the-energy-coming-from) question.  If you have a more specific question, please clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure that question mentions the change in structure of the paper, only what causes water to climb. Similarly the wikipedia article mentions what allows a surface to be wettened, but not structural effects. This doesn't really seem to address the question.

Comment: True, but the structural integrity was only provided as an example, it was not the focus of the question.  The question was very broad and, IMHO, needs to be narrowed.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of paper, fibers are connect to each other with hydrogen bonds. Water and humidity affect to these bonds and the fiber matrix loses its strength, or integrity.

In a more general way, water molecules tend to surround the charged particles (atoms, molecules) as they are polar.

Now, let these "charged particles" form the bonds of the material => water molecules surround them => particles bond with each other rather than other particles.