# Why do sponges work?

Tags: material-science, surface-tension

By "sponge" I mean anything used to suck up liquids from surfaces, such as kitchen towels etc. I assume capillary action is a factor, and also maybe surface area and surface energy. What are the factors involved and what makes a good sponge?

In other words, how can one predict the best materials for creating a sponge?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a sponge "suck" up water against gravity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66625/)

Comment: @JohnRennie Modified to actually ask for the direct information I want

Comment: In general something with very many very small cavities

Comment: @Jaywalker And what about the surface energy of the material? How much of an effect does that have?